# DataType Conversion from number to integer in pandas while writing to XML file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xml, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to convert the csv file to the desired output XML file.

**Input CSV**

```
Id,SubID,Rank,Size
1,123,1,0.1
1,234,2,0.2
2,123,1,0.1
2,456,2,0.2
```

**Output XML File**

```
<AA_ITEMS>
  <Id ID="1">
    <SubId ID="123.0">
     <Rank>1</Rank>
     <Size>0.1</Size>
    </SubId>
    <SubId ID="234.0">
      <Rank>2</Rank>
      <Size>0.2</Size>
    </SubId>
</Id>
<Id ID="2">
  <SubId ID="456.0">
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <Size>0.1</Size>
  </SubId>
  <SubId ID="123.0">
    <Rank>2</Rank>
    <Size>0.2</Size>
  </SubId>
```

**My Code Snippet to achieve the above**

```
root = ET.Element('AA_ITEMS')
        for o_id, df_group in df.groupby('ID'):
            coupon_codes = ET.Element('ID', {'ID': str(o_id)})
            for index,row in df_group.iterrows():
                substituted_code = ET.Element('SubID', {'ID': str(row['SubID'])})
                rank_code = ET.Element('RANK')
                rank_code.text = str(row['RANK'])
                pack_size_code = ET.Element('REL_PACK_SIZE')
                pack_size_code.text = str(row['REL_PACK_SIZE'])
                substituted_code.append(rank_code)
                substituted_code.append(pack_size_code)
                coupon_codes.append(substituted_code)
            root.append(coupon_codes)

        min_xml = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8')
        with open('/tmp/{}'.format(self.blob_name.split('.')[0]+'.xml'), "wb") as file:
            file.write(min_xml)
```

However the issue here is the value of the SubID is displayed in the number format("123.0","234.0","456.0") which should be same as that of the input file i.e integer ("123","234","456") without any decimal.

Please advise on how to achieve the above in my code

Comment: Hi, try replacing `str(row['SubID'])` with `str(int(row['SubID']))`.

Comment: Also, if you make a df of your csv with `pd.read_csv`, then you can get a result pretty close to the desired output XML file with just one line: `df.to_xml("file.xml", index=False, attr_cols=["Id", "SubID"], elem_cols=["Rank", "Size"], root_name="AA_ITEMS", row_name="Id", xml_declaration=False)`